# How can I change navigationBar Background

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, navigationbar

I try change to background of navigationBar.

Search.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Search : UIViewController

@end
```

Search.m:

```
#import "Search.h"

@implementation Search

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_header.png"];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

I can't change navigation background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually simpler to do then you think. In your app delegate...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    return YES;
}
```

This will universally change your navigation bar background image.

**Note:** I believe `UINavigationBar's` "appearance" property is available in iOS 5 and up.

Answer (score 2):

viewController.h

```
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
```

viewController.m
//for color

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{  
[super viewDidLoad];
 [navBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:20.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
}
```

//for image

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation_header.png"];
[self.navigationController.navBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Property 'navBar' not found on object of type 'UINavigationController *'

Comment: use this self.navigationController.navigationBar

Comment: the background image won't change because nb isn't hooked up to anything.

Comment: so? by the way, i have not "nb"

Comment: u customly added  navigationController ??

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[Search alloc] initWithNibName:@"Search" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.window addSubview:[navControl view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

Write this method in AppDelegate.m. I think it will be helpful to you.